# For $z \in \mathbb C$, define $f(z) = \frac {e^z}{e^z - 1}$, then

Tags: complex-analysis

1. $f$ is entire .
2. the only singularities of $f$ are poles.
3. $f$ has infinitely many poles on the imaginary axis
4. each pole of $f$ is simple.

For (1), Since $0$ is a pole of $f$, So $f$ is not entire.

For (2),(3) other Singularities of $f$ are $2n\pi i$, where n $\in \mathbb Z$

For (4), Since zeroes of $e^z - 1$ is $2n\pi i $ and deivative of $e^z - 1$ is $e^z$ is not equal to zero at $2n\pi i$. So (4) is true.

Comment: Looks right. ${}$

Comment: No proof of (2).

Comment: Assuming that you can actually prove $2$, then it's fine. Regardless, please don't make the title the first line of your question. Titles should describe the question, which should then be self-contained.

Comment: Writing in this way: $f(z)= 1/(1-e^{-z}) $and then $f(z)=(1-e^{-z})^{-1}= 1+(1-z+z^2/2!-z^3/3!+\cdots) +\cdots$. So there is no -ve powers of z. So I guess it should be entire. Also I agree with your points. Can someone sort out where I am doing the mistake?

Comment: @analysis, note that you're using the formula for the sum of a geometric series, and that sum only converges if the common ratio is less than 1 in modulus.

Comment: @analysis89 You expansion is not valid for all $z=x+iy \in\mathbb{C},$ only for $|e^{-z}|<1 \Leftrightarrow e^{-x}<1 \Leftrightarrow x>0\;.$

Comment: @ user 61527 : Thanks for advice, further i will kept in mind about the title of the question

Answer (score 2):

$f$ has singularity at the points, where $e^z=1$. And which, according to your calculation, are infinitely many, lies on imaginary axis. And each of them are pole. So, 2),3) and 4) are correct.